# mui simple carousel library implementing issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, carousel

Implementing a simple carousel using [react material-ui carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel) the **Invalid hook call** error rises.

Error occurred:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I simplified the documentation starter code as much as I could, but the error still remains.
Seems the dependency packages version looks correct and error just rise from the code I had no idea how to fix that.

My code:
[On stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-waftcp?file=demo.js)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Paper, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel';

const Demo = (props) => (
  <Carousel>
    {/* Change above line to <> and it work, maybe some version conflicts??  */}
    <Paper>
      <Typography>First Item</Typography>
      <Button variant="outlined">Click me please!</Button>
    </Paper>
    <Paper>
      <Typography>Second Item</Typography>
      <Button variant="outlined">Click me please!</Button>
    </Paper>
    <Paper>
      <Typography>Third Item</Typography>
      <Button variant="outlined">Click me please!</Button>
    </Paper>
  </Carousel>
);

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they havn't updated the package yet to support react 18 https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel/issues/174.

If you're using npm add:

```
  "overrides": {
    "react-material-ui-carousel": {
      "react": "^18.0.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
    }
  }
```

to package.json. Or if you're using yarn add:

```
 "resolutions": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
 }
```

I also had to delete both my package-lock.json and node_modules then run `npm install` but maybe try without first.